Ubuntu 24.04 [HP Omen AMD Radeon RX 6600M 8GB]
I updated from Ubuntu 22.04LTS to 23.04 and then to 24.04LTS. I noticed occasional mouse or screen freeze for a couple of days. Now it has become frequent, and the worst case scenario is it logs me out of the system, and when I log back in, I could see applications were also closed down. I had to reopen all.
Note: I have not installed the third party driver (AMD driver for the graphics), and uses default driver from the Ubuntu system.
How can I resolve this issue? Any ideas? Thanks.

Same problem with a Radeon RX6400, Kubuntu 24.04 wayland crashes the whole system after a few minutes, constantly. Unusable. Worst Ubuntu ever.
